# TFS Task Board: How to create an epic under another epic?

Tags: tfs

I'd like to create a hierarchy that involves two layers of epics. I've seen in done in other places but do not know how to do it. However, when I try to add another epic under my original epic, I'm only given the ability to create a Feature. This is what I'm looking to do:

- Epic

  - Epic

    - Feature
    - Feature
- Epic
- Epic

Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up the work item that you want to be the parent, then create a new child item of the type "Epic" beneath it.

In on-premise TFS, you could also modify the process template to put "Epic" as a potential child of "Epic", but I would recommend not changing the process template unless you absolutely have to do so.

[image]